# Evaluate GString at runtime with domain class binding

Tags: grails, groovy

I'd like to store a user configurable GString that would be bound to a domain class but I'm having a problem finding a nice solution to this.

Example (**concept/pseudo/non-working**)

```
class Person{
    ...

    String displayFooAs;  //<-- contains a java.lang.String like '${name} - ${address}'
}


class Foo{

    String name;
    String address;
    String city;

    public String getDisplayAs(def person){

        return doStuff(this, person.displayFooAs); //<-- Looking for something simple.

    }



}
```

UPDATE:

After review I've decided that this kind of flexibility would pose a **security risk**.  It would allow users to essentially script out sql injection into 'dispalyFooAs'.  Back to the drawing board.

Comment: What does it do?  Nothing?  Exception?

Comment: Sorry... this is just pseudo code.

Comment: @tim_yates I cleaned up example a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like:

```
public String getDisplayAs(def person){
  doStuff( this, person?.displayFooAs ?: "$name - $address" )
}
```

This works in Groovy, but I've never embedded SimpleTemplateEngine into something like this in Grails, so would require extensive testing to make sure it works as expected and doesn't gobble memory.

```
import groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine

class Person {
  String displayAs = 'Person $name'
}

class Foo {
  String name = 'tim'
  String address = 'yates'

  String getDisplayAs( Person person ) {
    new SimpleTemplateEngine()
          .createTemplate( person?.displayAs ?: '$name - $address' )
          .make( this.properties )
          .toString()
  }
}

def foo = new Foo()

assert foo.getDisplayAs( null )         == 'tim - yates'
assert foo.getDisplayAs( new Person() ) == 'Person tim'
```

Comment: Yes!  'doStuff' would evaluate the string against 'this'

Comment: You might want `'$name - $address'` with single quotes then, rather than double quotes which will be evaluated before it gets to `doStuff`

Comment: In that case it would seem okay to use double quotes because the elvis operator is in place to act as a default if a person isn't supplying an evaluating script.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Lee Added a Groovy example that works.  Significant testing is recommended before use in grails though ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You've defined

`private static final String DEFAULT_DISPLAY_AS = '${name} - ${address}'`

**static** and **final** - of course it doesn't work?

Define it's as closure

```
private def DEFAULT_DISPLAY_AS = {->'${name} - ${address}'}
```

and call in code

```
DEFAULT_DISPLAY_AS()
```

Comment: Sorry. This was just pseudo code.   The default would be used if the user didn't provide a custom one.

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar where I would evaluate the GString inside a closure loop so the template references it property values. I took the example above and formalized it into a standardized class for late GString evaluations.

```
import groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine

class EvalGString {
    def it
    def engine

    public EvalGString() {
        engine = new SimpleTemplateEngine()
    }

    String toString(template, props) {
        this.it = props
        engine.createTemplate(template).make(this.properties).toString()        
    }
}    

def template = 'Name: ${it.name} Id: ${it.id}'
def eval = new EvalGString()

println eval.toString(template, [id:100, name:'John')
println eval.toString(template, [id:200, name:'Nate')
```

Output:

Name: John Id: 100

Name: Nate Id: 200